# Mantine ScrollArea With React Infinite Scroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mantine, react-infinite-scroll-component

I am currently building an app which uses [Mantine](https://mantine.dev/) components. I have a list which I am paginating, and rendering using [React-Infinite-Scroll-Component](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component). I want to change the style of the scrollbar of the `InfiniteScroll` component to look like the Mantine `ScrollArea` scroll bar, is there a way to use the `ScrollArea` component to wrap it? If not, how would I go about styling the scroll bar?

Have a look at this [CodeSandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-easley-0x42v1?file=/src/pages/index.tsx) to see exactly what the difference is.

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).